# Problem with wrong DEM output after georeferencing

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, ground-control

My goal is to georeference a DEM tiff file that I have with a reference orthophoto.

### Steps to reproduce

- Open orthophoto (EPSG2056) in QGIS
- Open the DEM (EPSG2056) in the Georeferencer
- Add GCP (I am using the from map canvas option).
- Set transformation Settings to Linear, EPSG2056, uncheck set target resolution
- Launch the georeferencer
  [image: Georeferencer with GCPs]
  What I expect if a new tiff file that will line up with my orthomosaic.

### Problem

What I get is a strange result, far away.

The extent is completely off:
(-22806.9832892952508701,-34274.8274427327123703 : -14579.3610109209384973,-25319.3653756338026142)

but the CRS is correct.
It also looks strange, as if it was tiled.
[image: Tiled(?) DEM]

I had a similair problem when georeferencing the orthophoto - that was already (badly) georeferenced. What solved it was to strip the georeferencement (in Gimp > Export in PNG) and start the georeferencing from there.
When applying the same steps with the DEM, it is losing information and appears black and white.

I am using QQGIS 3.26.
I tried using a new profile, and to do the same on 3.22 but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any idea how to solve this? I need both layers to be aligned, the orthophoto being correct.

### UPDATE

So I got the same file (DSM from drone aerial images) but without any CRS and I tried georeferencing that. The result I get is geographically closer to what I want but still very wrong:
[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue. The georeferenced TIF is in the correct area but there is no elevation data jus the white field and speckled borders. In some cases I get yellow colored stripe on one side. I have used both Georeferencer and the Freehand Raster Georeferencer plugin. The plugin makes a png file which will not support the 32 elevation data.